# How to design this kind of page using obj c

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

hiii every one i am new to iphone development in a sample downloaded app i have seen a page like this [image]

can anybody tell me how to design this kind of page using objective c

Comment: APPARENTLY...... that app integrates paypal api for iOS :)

Comment: @sunajledif ya i know,,but how they are creating this kind of design, do u have any idea

Comment: I think this is not developed with objective -c , But it is a hybrid app developed with HTML,Java script & CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems more like HTML/CSS to me. Designing such a page using Obj-C may be pretty hard. You can design a page like this in HTML/CSS and integrate it in your app inside a UIWebView. This may not be what you want though.

Answer (score 2):

You should really go through some apple sample codes which deal with UI creation.

**1.** You can use `UITextfield` with round rect corners .

**2.** You can use `UIButtons`. of type `custom` with images that you need.

**3.** `UIImageViews`, and set Images to them.

We won't really know what you're asking for unless you've told what you've **tried.**

Answer (score 1):

It's `UITextFields`, `UIButtons`, `UILabels`, `UIImages`, etc. in different `UIViews`. Is that what you needed?